# Unary Operation Using For Loops In Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, unary-operator

I'm trying to do some basic arithmetic within a `for` loop in MatLab.

Basically I want to copy and operate on each element one-by-one.  First I want to subtract 3.6: `testDataMean` from each element, raise each element to the power of `2` then sum up each variable.  The finally divide the variable `s` by `5` (`sizeOfTestData`)

This should calculate approximately ~1.05.

The `testData` variable is a 1x5 vector containing the numbers `3, 4, 2, 5, 4`

```
   s = 0;

for k = 1:sizeTestData
    p = testData(k);
    q = p - testDataMean;
    r = q^2;
    s = s + r;
    s/5;

end
```

This loop actually throws an error on the last line `s = s + r`.  I am aware I can use the `sum` function in most circumstances when operating on vectors of the same size, but in the context of a for loop I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the error? "Matrix dimensions must agree"?

Comment: Sorry it says, " Undefined Function or variable 's' "

Comment: Well, you have your answer there. Put `s = 0` in front of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `sum(s) / numel(s)` by definition is the same as `mean(s)`.

## The loop free approach:

```
testData = [3, 4, 2, 5, 4]
q = testData - mean(testData);
s = mean(q.^2);
s = 1.0400
```

## The one-liner:

```
s = mean((testData-mean(testData)).^2)
s = 1.0400
```

## And your initial approach:

(After bug fixing)

```
testData = [3, 4, 2, 5, 4]

s = 0;
sizeTestData = length(testData);
testDataMean = mean(testData);

for k = 1:sizeTestData
   p = testData(k);
   q = p - testDataMean;
   r = q^2;
   s = s + r;  
end
s = s / numel(s);
s = 1.0400
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry I missed a vital point at the end which was to divide the summed up variable `s` by `5`.  I've edited my original post to suit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give your solution a try, but yes that's what I wanted.  I'm just practising the concept of a RMSE (root mean squared error).

Comment: @user1574598: Programming Matlab efficiently is very much about avoiding loops whenever possible. Daniel's one-liner is therefore not just one but *the* Matlab way to compute the RMSE. Except that it's possible to do it even shorter: `s = var(testData, 1)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks, thats useful to know about avoiding loops :-)  I'll keep on practising and hopefully get better.  Its amazing how 6-8 lines of code can be reduced to one!